# Several instances of a fragment are reusing the same Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, fragmenttransaction

Today I've been facing a very weird situation.

When creating several instances of a fragment, let's say `MyFragment`, and then I replace them making use of the `FragmentTransaction` to commit the changes, all of them are reusing the same `Bundle` of the first created instance.

I use a public static method as a "factory" to create every single instances of `MyFragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String FRAG_TAG = "MyFragment";

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int myIntArgValue) {
          final MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
          final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putInt("myIntArg", myIntArgValue);
          frag.setArguments(bundle);
          return frag;
    }

   /** Other relevant methods of the fragment. */
}
```

Then I add all of my instances to the stack one after another:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
final MyFragment frag = MyFragment.newInstance(position); // position is always a different value
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag, MyFragment.FRAG_TAG).addToBackStack("BACK_STACK_TAG"); // I already tried ft.add(...) or ft.remove(this).replace(...);
ft.commit();
```

So, for 2 instances of this fragment like `MyFragment.newInstance(1);` and `MyFragment.newInstance(2);`
the `getArguments().getInt("myIntArg")` always returns 1 (the value of the very first created instance).

To solve the problem I've done something like:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
final MyFragment frag = MyFragment.newInstance(position);
final Bundle args = frag.getArguments();
args.remove("myIntArg");
args.putInt("myIntArg", position /** The value I really want to and should be used by the "factory" */);
frag.setArguments(args); // I can to this because the fragment is not yet attached
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag, MyFragment.FRAG_TAG).addToBackStack("BACK_STACK_TAG");
ft.commit();
```

I know this shouldn't be done this way but it works.
Does anybody have faced with such a thing like this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could that be happening because you are using final when declaring the Bundle? Did you really check if the value your are setting for "myIntArg" is always different?

Comment: I've already tried without `final` and its the same thing. And yes, I'm 100% sure that "myIntArg" is always different.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
 frag.setArguments(frag);
```

Shouldn't you set arguments to bundle?

Comment: Sorry Miles. Very well catched... my bad writing the question. But unfortunately my code is well written. `frag.setArguments(frag);` wouldn't even compile. I'll edit the post. Thanks!